# Monitor bandwidth usage from different virtual hosts

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, bandwidth

I've got a VPS running Ubuntu and Apache and hosting several sites on it using virtual hosts. It would be very interesting to monitor which of these sites takes the most power and bandwidth, I've been looking for a tool for that but haven't found any. Do you guys know a tool or a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a tool for this, apache is capable of tracking this itself.
To accomplish this you need to set up logging to log out the size of each response by the web server. You can either place both virtualhosts into the same log file (and just add the virtualhost name to each log entry), or put them in separate log files.

To create log entries in the `logs/transfer` file with 3 fields, the virtual host, the bytes received, and the bytes sent (requires [`mod_logio`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_logio.html))

```
CustomLog logs/transfer "%v %I %O"
```

If you do not have `mod_logio`, you can log the bytes sent back (not including headers) with

```
CustomLog logs/transfer "%v %B"
```

You can consult the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) on the available log parameters.

Comment: That sounds good but I still need to create my own tool for visualizing the data in that case. What I was looking for was more of a complete solution for it

Answer (score 0):

`wireshark` can do this on the network level. It should be enough to look at the IP-headers for your purpose.